# Show Text once Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want the text to be displayed once the checkbox is checked. It works perfectly without a class on my checkbox but I can't get my text displayed if I put a class on my checkbox. I need to put style in my checkbox. Here is my code, I want to know why the js gets affected by the class attribute.

Contract
 Checkbox is CHECKED!

```
      <script>
           function myFunction() {
                   var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
                   var text = document.getElementById("text");
                        if (checkBox.checked == true){                                                                         
                           text.style.display = "block";                                                                    
                         } 
                        else {                                                                        
                           text.style.display = "none";                                                                      
                         }
                      }
             </script>
```

Comment: Your code is working just fine for me. Maybe some other piece of code is affecting this?

Comment: your code is working properly, please check there might be some another issue.

Comment: This is my checkbox <input  type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="flat" onclick="myFunction()">Contract
 <p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

Comment: It works, but after I put a class on my checkbox to put style on it, the text won't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working just fine for me.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.flat {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" class="flat" onclick="myFunction()">Contract
<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

Comment: I got it right already, I just unspecifically called my flat class :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an element with the id of "text", yet you're attempting to get one here:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
```

You can add it to your paragraph element: i.e. 
`<p id="text">` 
but this will also cause your checkbox to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox try "firebug" add on.
It may help you debug the issues in your javascript OR css.
At-least it ha helped me many times in the past.
Here is the link--
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/